# Inject Environment Variables at runtime with Webpack Module federation

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

The question about injecting Environment Variables **after** bundling with *Webpack* is already asked and answered.

The answer is always based on loading the updated Environment Variables inside the **`index.html`** file.

But when using [Webpack Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/), we are exposing **only a `component.js` file**, so how can I bundle the source **during the `docker build`** phase, but read the Environment Variables during the **serving** phase (when running our bundle as a pod inside k8s, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Currently, we are combining the [`webpack.EnvironmentPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) with *Docker*.

In `webpack.config.js`, we are substituting the Environment Variables with a special string:

```js
plugins: [
    new EnvironmentPlugin({
        MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR: '{{MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}}',
        ANOTHER_ENV_VAR: '{{ANOTHER_ENV_VAR}}',
    }),
],
```

It means, **during the build time**, if there are no such Environment Variables, the bundle will include the strings `'{{MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}}'` and `'{{MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}}'`.

Now, to replace those variables **on container starts**, we are adding a substitute to the `RUN` command:

```bash
CMD sed -i "s@{{MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}}@${MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/*.bundle*.js \
    && sed -i "s@{{ANOTHER_ENV_VAR}}@${ANOTHER_ENV_VAR}@g" /usr/share/nginx/html/*.bundle*.js \
    && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

(It will replace the string `{{MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}}` with the value of `${MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VAR}` on the bundle files: `/usr/share/nginx/html/*.bundle*.js` (nginx))

Answer (score 0):

I'm strugling with the same issue... And I can only think of using a convention in the container for handling this problem.

All micro-frontends could potentially expose their environment variables in ./assets/env.template.js (then finally ./assets/env.js) with ${MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} as placeholders.

This env.template.js will be an autoexecuting javascript function that will just introduce the environment variable values as global properties of the window (see below the example).

**env.template.js**

```js
(function (window) {
  window.env = window.env || {};
  window['env']['clientId'] = '${CLIENT_ID}';
  window['env']['baseUrl'] = '${BASE_URL}'
})(this);
```

When creating the docker image a final asset env.js will be generated that will substitute the environment variables. For example creating the docker nginx image with:

`CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]`

The container when loading the remotes could try to dynamically load their env.js files exposed in assets.

The normal angular injected environment would get the values from the window.env the values.

Comment: Finally I ended with a similar solution but a little more elegant because we use dynamic module federation.

Our container loads the microfrontends based on a configuration that describes their remote entries and available modules. Before solving this problem we just had 'routing' module type (used by the root routing module to build the routes) and 'other' module type (used for other types of plugin modules like dashboard widgets,...). 
In order to solve the problem we added a new startup module type that will be loaded at startup and this one will be the responsible of loading the env.js

Answer (score -2):

**In the webpack.config**

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');       
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
```

Then in the plugin modules part add this

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env);
}),
```

This will bring to code all Environment Variables from the machine.

Another improvement is required this way, with this you can create files like `.env.development` or `.env.production`

```js
module.exports = (env, args) => {
    require("dotenv").config({ path: `./.env.${args.mode}` });
```

**If you want to pass just the env vars you define in the .env files just change the require to this:**

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({ path: ./.env.${args.mode}` });
```

and the definePlugin to this:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed), }),
```

Comment: But please note, all those solutions are available during the `webpack` command- the "build" time. Now let's say I already bundled my code, and I created a Docker Image with it. How can I launch the container with some Env Vars that will be used inside the bundle?

Comment: you can build the application inside a Dockerfile, just use entry point commands

Comment: But then the load takes time

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Getting environment variables into a docker container at build time is a solved problem. The question is about runtime, which does not have widely-understood solutions.